# How to trigger a CI automatically after a MR is merged into master

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, webhooks

I want to automate clean up process(trigger a clean up CI job) in gitlab CI pipeline. Anyone knows how to trigger a cleanup CI job or similar process after merge request is merged ?

Answer (score 1):

The key to having any continuous integration job triggered upon a merge request is to include the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of the project.

The file is YAML, and it's fairly easy to call on various resource within the file. It really depends on what your objective is when you say 'clean up.' It's not uncommon to call Maven within these YAML files and perhaps do a Maven clean. You can also invoke Git commands if you need to delete or prune branches.

So first, make sure the YAML file is there. Secondly, code your clean up needs into the file. That should do it.